# sudo does not ask for password

Tags: sudo

Whenever I issue command `sudo apt-get install foo` it does not ask for password.
is it because of user groups?

How to make it prompt for password?

Edit: My sudoers file

```
apple@Ascension:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: is your user login password blank or auto-login?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not ask for password' , did the command get executed ? Did you receive any output ?

Comment: @izx it is neither blank nor auto-login.

Comment: @warl0ck yep, command get executed without password prompt.

Comment: share your /etc/sudoers please

Comment: @warl0ck provided sudoers file

Comment: remove the last 3 lines of sudoers , your problem will be solved.

Comment: @warl0ck I didn't edit sudoers then how it get appended in sudoers. Can you explain? BTW it is solved now.

Comment: @virpara the last three lines functions as single one , that will anyone in any machine to launch any commands without password prompting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the command `sudo visudo` you can see and edit, the sudo configuration, for example :

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Group without password
%nopwd  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Your current user is probably member of a privileged group that enables him to enter sudo commands without password. In this example members of `admin` and `sudo` group can issue any command with sudo, but are prompted with a password ; members of the `nopwd` group are not prompted with a password.

Note that the declaration order is relevant for users belonging to multiple groups. Unintuitively, the LAST matching group wins !

In order to require a password, you can add the `PASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get` command specification in file `/etc/sudoers` ; note that you probably want to **allow** specific commands with no password, and keep every other command with a password. An example explicitely requesting a password for apt-get:

```
%users  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, PASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Note that you can personnalize sudo with a much finer granularity than *allow all commands* like in my first example ([doc ubuntu fr](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/sudoers))([doc ubuntu en](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)).