# Sudoers file, enable NOPASSWD for user, all commands

Tags: sudo

#### Preface

This is a fairly complex question related to the sudoers file and the sudo command in general.

NOTE: I have made these changes on a dedicated machine running Ubuntu Desktop 13.04, that I use purely for learning purposes. I understand it's a huge security risk to enable NOPASSWD sudo.

#### Question

Initially, my only change to the sudoers file (`/etc/sudoers`) was one line, a user specification that should have enabled nicholsonjf to run all commands with sudo without having to enter a password (see the line that starts with nicholsonjf):

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
nicholsonjf    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

However this did not work, and I was still prompted for my password every time I ran a command as nicholsonjf. I was only able to start running sudo commands as nicholsonjf once I removed nicholsonjf from the sudo and admin groups.

Can anyone explain why this worked?

Is it because the user nicholsonjf was inheriting sudo rights from the two group specifications of `admin` and `sudo` (seen below in the sudoers file), which were overriding the nicholsonjf user specification because they were further down in the config file?

Comment: note: ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL has to be ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL or else it doesn't work...

Comment: see also this answer : http://askubuntu.com/questions/139723/sudo-does-not-ask-for-password/139733#139733

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is sudoers NOPASSWD option not working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working)

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The line you added was overridden. From `man sudoers`:

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

In your case `nicholsonjf` was a member of the group `sudo` so for him this line applied:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If you want to override entries in `/etc/sudoers` just put the new entries after them.

The new entry should look like

`myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` for a single user, or

`%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` for a group.

Comment: For a complete solution I would like to see something about `NOPASSWD` in this answer...

Comment: I think, the solution should be: `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: @DanielAlder: The specification line from the question `nicholsonjf    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` is correct. It was just at a wrong place as I explained in the answer. ------ The `Runas` specification — in your case `(ALL)` — is optional. If you omit the specification you can run the commands as `root` and you cannot use `-u` and `-g` options of `sudo`.

Comment: This is a worse security risk as it gives multiple users passwordless access. If it's your personal PC then that's not significant - perhaps. I'd just move the personal line, to last.

Comment: An addition, rather than correction, if using something debian/ubuntu based (may be generally applied, not seen it elsewhere) Your absolute best-practice bet is to add custom commands to a file in /etc/sudoers.d/ and leave sudoers itself to be managed by the package manager.

Answer (score 153):

For a single user, add this line at the end of your `sudoers` file using the `sudo visudo` command:

```
superuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

For a group

```
%supergroup  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Before I read this answer I did `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` and it works. Am I the only one who finds Extended Backus-Naur Form really hard to understand?

Comment: @Vince When used your command I can't `sudo` without password as user without sudo privileges. E.g. `sudo -u root -i` works, but `sudo -u git -i` doesn't.

Answer (score 56):

Run this command to never prompt the current user for a password when that user uses `sudo`:

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee "/etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-$USER-for-sudo-password"
```

It creates a file called `/etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-<YOUR USERNAME>-for-sudo-password` with the following contents:

```
<YOUR USERNAME> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

This works because Debian's and Ubuntu's default `/etc/sudoers` file has this line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

which makes it process files in the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. If the command above didn't work, check that no one has removed that line from your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: I like the shortcut working for the current user

Comment: This is only way that worked here in Mint.

Comment: This is actually "the" correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoMassenzio you're welcome, yea I felt like I was going a little crazy when I stumbled upon that directory and as I was writing this up because I'd been coming to this question every time I installed Ubuntu, everyone needs to do it, this is clearly the best way to do it over manually editing a file every time, it's been supported since the 90's and I've never seen anybody mention it anywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

As [Vince](https://askubuntu.com/users/211620/vince) has [mentioned in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands/961906#comment1071337_574454), you can use this line:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(This is different from the lines shown in [those](https://askubuntu.com/a/574454/22949) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/340669/22949), and it solved the problem for me.)

Comment: @Eliah this is not that different from the other answers. All it does is replace the placeholder `supergroup` in Fedir's answer with `sudo`. What next, another user for the group `wheel`? Or any other group the user happens to be using?

Comment: @muru *"All it does is replace the placeholder `supergroup` in Fedir's answer with `sudo`."* ***What?*** Replacing `supergroup` with `sudo` in the line `%supergroup  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` yields `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`, not `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`.

Comment: Which is arguably worse, since now NOPASSWD is only for root as the target user. So, it doesn't even answer the question correctly!

Comment: @muru What is is *not even arguably*, however, is a substitution of `supergroup` with `sudo`. This is its own answer, not a thanks post or a copy of another answer. But yes, I agree: [unless they intend that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands/961906?noredirect=1#comment1319629_574454), this will not be as good for most users as the methods in the other answers. (But, especially considering the question says "all commands," not "all target users," I don't think this is in effect not even attempting to answer the question that was asked.)

Comment: This worked for me and I wanted to share with other users :) (remove my comment if desired).

Answer (score 2):

As I was researching this, I realized that there's a line in the `/etc/sudoers` file that is not a comment, but a **directive** that makes any file or folder under the directory `/etc/sudoers/*` override the contents of `/etc/sudoers`.

This is a sneaky little directive, as it appears to be a commented line upon first glance. It looks like this:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This is how I've implemented the non-root, passwordless user in an ephemeral Docker Image for use in a CICD pipeline with the base image of ubuntu:18.04:

```
RUN \
  useradd -U foo -m -s /bin/bash -p foo -G sudo && passwd -d foo && passwd -d root && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
  sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## Removed the #include directive! ##"/g' && \
  echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access!" && \
  echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
  echo "root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
  echo "foo user:";  su foo -c 'whoami && id' && \
  echo "root user:"; su root -c 'whoami && id'
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Comment: You don't need to remove the directive if you don't have any files in that directory.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The reason I've "disabled" this directive in the above snippet is to make certain the script works. Great callout though for those unaware

Answer (score 0):

One can insert a string in one line without EOF formatting at end of sudoers file or remove with `sed -i`:

`cat >> /etc/sudoers <<<'PaSe  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'`

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298208/how-to-append-a-line-at-the-end-of-etc-sudoers-file-using-shell-script-without/70039824#70039824

Answer (score 0):

To give explicit permission for each command you want allow, (extending the answer of [user677955](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162819/682513))

Example to bypass passwdord prompt for `sudo apt [...]` in **bash**:

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:$(which apt)" \
| sudo tee -a "/etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-$USER-for-sudo-password"
```

Example to bypass password prompt for `sudo service [...]` in **fish**:

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:"(which service) \
| sudo tee -a "/etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-$USER-for-sudo-password"
```