# What should I do when I get 'There are stopped jobs' error?

Tags: process, emacs, job-control

I face this type of situation many times.

For example, whenever I try to open some file in `emacs` with `sudo` rights using:

`sudo emacs tet.c &`

Instead of asking me for the password Ubuntu just starts `emacs` process without any `emacs` window or any  output on terminal (except for the pid) see the image (if I don't use '&' then it will ask me for the password):

[image]

I have two questions related with this:

1. What should I do when I get error that 'There are stopped jobs'? How
   do I identify all such stopped jobs and kill them? Once I clear the
   terminal I won't have pids of these stopped processes.
2. Why is Ubuntu/emacs behaving like this? Why doesn't it ask me for
   the password?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`There are stopped jobs` message is *far, far away* to be an error. It's just a notification telling you that you attempt to exit from the shell, but you have one or more suspended jobs/programs (in your case `emacs` which you putted in background using `&` at the end of your command). The system doesn't let you to exit from the shell and kill the jobs unless you mean to. You can do a couple of things in response to this message:

- use `jobs` command to tell you what job(s) you have suspended
- you can choose to add the job(s) in the foreground using `fg` command
- if you don't care if the job(s) will terminate, you can just type `exit` again; typing `exit` a second time with or without an intervening `jobs` command will result in the termination of all suspended jobs.

To answer the second question, I will tell you that not Ubuntu or emacs behaving like this. This is a normal behavior when you put an application to run in background. In this case `sudo` is asking for password, but is asking in background, so you can't see this fact. To see it, you should bring back the job in foreground using `fg` command:

```
radu@Radu: ~ $ sudo emacs tet.c &
[1] 7732
radu@Radu: ~ $ # now sudo emacs run in background so you can't see nothing about what's happening
radu@Radu: ~ $ fg
[sudo] password for radu:
```

After this you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to put again the job in background if you want. Then you can run again 'fg' command to bring back the job in foreground and so on.

Comment: For me, its always telnet. I forget to `quit` :) (see http://superuser.com/questions/486496/how-do-i-exit-telnet)

Comment: So, I just pressed Ctrl+d twice (!) and got the same message after the first one. Is there any way to figure out what was the job I just killed?

Answer (score 27):

You got the message, because system warns you about active jobs associated with your current shell.

You can list these running/stopped jobs by running: `jobs`,

Then you can do one of the following:

- move last job to the foreground by: `fg` (opposite of `bg` for background),
- run `disown` to remove these jobs from your current shell without killing them,
- force logout by killing these tasks by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice, same as typing `exit`/`logout` twice,
- kill these jobs manually by running: `kill $(jobs -p)` (add `-9` for force)
- if you disown them, and you want to still kill all stopped processes, try:

  `kill $(ps wuax | awk 'NR>1 && $8 ~ "T" {print $2}')`

---

To answer question about `sudo`, it won't ask you for the password, as it requires to have active terminal in order to receive the password from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), and by running it the background, the shell doesn't wait for the command to finish, so you don't have possibility to interact with the command.

In this case, you've 3 possibilities:

- run command without going into background (`&`),
- read the password from standard input instead of the terminal device by `sudo -S` e.g.

  ```
  echo mypass | sudo emacs tet.c
  ```
- configure sudo to not ask for the password by: `visudo` command and editing `sudoers` file. See: [Enable `NOPASSWD` for user](https://askubuntu.com/q/334318/78223)

Answer (score 11):

When you encounter **there are stopped jobs** error:

1. type`jobs`--> you will see the jobs with stopped status
2. and then type `exit`--> you can get out of the terminal

Comment: Thank you, "jobs" is what I was looking for.