# File '/etc/sudoers': Why do I need to use the sudo command if I am in the sudo group?

Tags: permissions, sudo

My user account on Ubuntu is `olivier`.

When I type the command `groups olivier` it returns:

```
olivier : olivier adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

So I am deducing I belong to the `sudo` group.

I have the following lines in my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If the members of group `sudo` can execute any commands, why do I need to use the `sudo` command when I want to execute a command with privileges (for example, a `rm` on a folder where I am not the owner) whereas I am logged with the user `olivier`?

Comment: Because that is the mechanism to escalate privileges to root, If you do not enter sudo, your command will run as your user and not as root. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo. If you still have a question after reading that page, post back =)

Comment: It is a simple security measure, so that when you leave your computer while logged in no one can access those commands and mess stuff up for you. If you want to change that we have already some great answers on this site on how to do so. [Q&A: Sudoers file, enable NOPASSWD for user, all commands](https://askubuntu.com/q/334318/522934) for example and from there are so many cross linked that you probably will find a solution.

Comment: in my sudoers file I have these line : `# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` I don't understand what is the difference with `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. When I am logged as root with `sudo su` I type any command

Comment: You can type any command when you're root, because root is the owner for almost the whole file-system.

Comment: Let's ask a different question... why would the contents of the `sudoers` file have *any effect* on what you can and can't do, if you aren't using `sudo`? Osmosis?

Comment: Basically, that comment should say `#Allow members of group sudo to execute any command via sudo`. I guess whoever wrote it thought that the last two words are implied by the comment being in the `sudoers` file, i.e. the config file for `sudo`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having one's userid (or a group one is a member of) in the `sudoers` file gives one the *capability* to run commands as `root` (or other users, but that's advanced `sudoers`). It does **NOT** make one `root` all the time, which is what you seem to be assuming.

Speaking from a half century's experience with computers, being `root` all the time is too dangerous. Having to type `sudo` in front of the command gives one extra time to consider - will this shoot me in the foot?

Please read `man sudo`, `man sudoers`, `man sudo_root`.

Comment: What I don't understand are these lines in my sudoers file `# User privilege specification root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` and `# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, the lines are exactly the same so why the members of sudo group can't do the same thing as the root user ?

Comment: The members of the sudo group can do the same things as root user. This is accomplished via the sudo tool, which is what the sudoers file controls.

Comment: Please read `man sudo`, `man sudoers`, `man sudo_root`.

Comment: Ok so this is the basic behavior of ubuntu, only the root user can do everything he wants on the system, What I still don't understand is why are there an admin an a sudo group on ubuntu, if the group sudo can execute every command on the system, the admin group is useless ?

Comment: AskUbuntu comments are not for extending questions or conversations.

Comment: Also, since I never like the "We do this so you won't mess up your own system" argument, here's one with more reason: Sometimes you want to run the command as your user, and other times you want to run it as root. This gives you flexibility. Could you imagine, not knowing what commands are going to run as your user ID, and what would run as root? How would you know if you didn't have to put sudo before it?

Comment: @DanChase: David Richerby's answer on [Is it 'OK' to use the root user as a normal user?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192365/is-it-ok-to-use-the-root-user-as-a-normal-user) makes a pretty good argument (with funny but good analogies) for the avoiding breakage from typos argument.