# How can I write/modify the root directory file through single line command ( Using ROOT password )

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ssh, password

I had been trying to write `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file as a normal user.

In search of that from somewhere I got this,
`echo "PermitRootLogin" yes | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Also, I got to know that "I can explicitly pass the root password for any `sudo` command on the same line"

 Like `echo <password> | sudo -S apt-get install tmux`

So, my question is how can I merge these two commands and make a single command, that appends the `PermitRootLogin yes` to the specified file as a normal user using a root password.

Comment: Don't! Use `sudoers` config if you need to allow [passwordless `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands?rq=1). Be aware of the consequences!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pLumo, I got to know that method by which I was trying to achieve the results is Insecure. So I will look up  `sudoers`.

Comment: @pLumo Yeah, `-S` is necessary, I forgotten

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a nested `bash -c` or `sh -c` command:

```bash
echo "mypassword" | sudo -S bash -c 'tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config <<< "PermitRootLogin yes"'

#or

echo "mypassword"  | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "PermitRootLogin" yes | tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config'
```

**Note, this is fairly unsafe**. Consider at least adding `sudo -S` to `HISTIGNORE` ([see also](https://superuser.com/a/844957)).

Generally better option would be to use [`sudoers` configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) to [allow some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) ([or all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands?rq=1)) commands passwordless.

---

Anyways, it is generally a **very** bad idea to allow `root` login through `ssh`!

Comment: Yeah, That one is very Helpful, thanks @pLumo. Your suggestions will help me further, I will remember them.