# Sudo is not asking for password on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, users

Ever since I update to 16.04 I notice whenever I use any sudo command the terminal does not ask me the password before executing the command,The command is directly executed.I am the admin and I have no other user accounts.

I have seen [sudo does not ask for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139723/sudo-does-not-ask-for-password) and my /etc/sudoers is exactly like given in answer but still when using sudo command, terminal does not prompt a password instead execute the command.

I would like to know in detail how can `/etc/sudoers` can be modified for

- Making any particular user account(including admin) to  be prompted or not prompted for password when using sudo command.
- How to exclude any particular command to be excluded from prompting password when using sudo for any user account(including admin).

Here is my sudoers file

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0

# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
# %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification root ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Output of sudo -l

```
Matching Defaults entries for bharat on ratcoder:
    env_reset, timestamp_timeout=0

User bharat may run the following commands on ratcoder:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo -l`.

Comment: @muru Please see I have added it in the question itself.

Comment: some file in `/etc/sudoers.d` has the NOPASSWD rule. Find and delete it

Comment: @muru how can I do it? There are 3 files in '/etc/sudoers.d' and they don't open.

Comment: `sudo grep NOPASSWD /etc/sudoers.d -R`

Comment: @muru Now I am getting error `bharat is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: Sigh.. You didn't restore the default rule before doing that? Run `pkexec visudo` and add `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL` before the `includedir` line.

Comment: @muru Thanks it helped. Would you please write the answer so that I can accept it and move on. I don't like unanswered questions. And if possible please write how can particular can be excluded so that they don't require password using sudo. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a `NOPASSWD` rule applied to your user in some file in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Use `sudo grep NOPASSWD /etc/sudoers.d -R` to find out which.

Your `/etc/sudoers` is not the default, however. The default `sudoers` can be obtained by looking at the `sudo` package:

```
$ apt-get download sudo
Get:1 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.1 [389 kB]
Fetched 389 kB in 0s (4,750 kB/s)
$ dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile sudo*.deb | tar x ./etc/sudoers
$ cat etc/sudoers 
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This is rather different from what you have. Restore `/etc/sudoers` to the default.

For excluding specific commands from requiring a password, see [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your *sudoers* file using `sudo visudo`.

Find this line: `Defaults        env_reset` and change it to this:

`Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0`

This forces sudo to ask for a password every time your run it.

Comment: Editing with this does not change anything still sudo does not prompt for password, and I would like to know how to exclude(or include) specific command or user.

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't mention which user is the admin user. Likely it is a created user account (and so this may not apply), but for other people who come across this thread I mention this: when using the current Ubuntu 16.04 AMI on AWS, the `ubuntu` user by default does not require a password for `sudo` so that `cloud-init` can use it to execute. This access is defined in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`, like so:

```
# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: 1. Was setting a root password and ubuntu user password a useless thing to do? 2. Is this safe that a user (ubuntu) doesn't require root password?